# Prove that the series $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges in $X$.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in a Banach space $X$ such that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \|a_n\|\lt \infty$. Prove that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges in $X$.

---

To show convergence of this sum, I want to let there be a sequence taking a value for each $n$ right? I.e. $\{b_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ where $b_n = \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ and show that this is convergent. I know I don't need to worry about the completeness aspect since we are in a Banach space.

Should I argue along the lines $|b_n| \leq \displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^\infty \|a_n\| \lt \infty$, then some sort of Cauchy sequence argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to show that the series of partial sums is Cauchy,  thus it converges.   So,  look at the difference between two partial sums: $$\| \sum _{k=1}^na_k-\sum _{k=1}^ma_k\|<\epsilon $$ for all $n,m>N$  for some $N\in \mathbb N$.  Without loss of generality, assume $n>m$,  then we can rewrite the partial sum as 
$$\|\sum _{k=m+1}^na_k\|<\epsilon $$
Use the triangle inequality to get 
$$\|\sum _{k=m+1}^na_k\|<\sum _{k=m+1}^n\|a_k\| $$
But the latter sum is the tail of a convergent sequence, so it goes to $0$,  and you're done.

Comment: Thanks, that was very clear and helped me understand the relevant part of the chapter in Kreyszig's intro to funct analysis

Comment: No problem, I'm on chapter 7 right now of Kreyszig myself :)

Answer (score 2):

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. To show $S_n$ is Cauchy, note that for $m > n$,
$$||S_m - S_n|| = ||\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k || \leq \sum_{k=n+1}^m ||a_k||,$$
the latter of which can be made small since the series of norms converges (hence is Cauchy).